# Jquery Input Field Validation: How to find the closest span by its class name on input keypress event

Tags: jquery

i want to show warning message on span of any input that only takes number.I am using class for span because i have many inputs that only takes number.

Here is html & css:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      //called when key is pressed in input of class number_only
      $(".number_only").keypress(function (e) {
       //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
       if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 46 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
       //display error message
       $(this).closest('.errmsg').html("Digits and single dot Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
       return false;
       }
       });
    });
```

```css
    .errmsg {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group" style="">
      <input type="text"  id='input_1' class="form-control number_only">
      <span class="errmsg"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style="">
      <input type="text"  id='input_2' class="form-control number_only">
      <span class="errmsg"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style="">
      <input type="text"  id='input_3' class="form-control number_only">
      <span class="errmsg"></span> 
    </div>
```

the above code is not getting the closest span. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)  instead of [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). its search next nearest element.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      //called when key is pressed in input of class number_only
      $(".number_only").keypress(function (e) {
       //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
       if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 46 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
       //display error message
       $(this).next('.errmsg').html("Digits and single dot Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
       return false;
       }
       });
    });
```

```css
.errmsg {
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group" style="">
      <input type="text"  id='input_1' class="form-control number_only">
      <span class="errmsg"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style="">
      <input type="text"  id='input_2' class="form-control number_only">
      <span class="errmsg"></span> 
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style="">
      <input type="text"  id='input_3' class="form-control number_only">
      <span class="errmsg"></span> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`closest` searches for parents, `.siblings()` needs to be used here

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in input of class number_only
  $(".number_only").keypress(function (e) {
         //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
         if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && e.which != 46 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            //display error message
            $(this).siblings('.errmsg').html("Digits and single dot Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
         }
   });
});
```

[jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)